# using bc in bash script

Tags: bash, bc

I am trying outputing result in floating point using bc in bash.But I am getting the following output for the following code.How can i get the multiplication result from here and also why i am getting command not found.

```
 #!/bin/bash 
 v1=3.41 
 v2=45 
 v3= $(bc <<< "scale=4;$v1 + $v2")
 echo $v3 
 v3= $(bc <<< "scale=4;$v1 - $v2") 
 echo $v3 
 v3= $(bc <<< "scale=4;$v1 / $v2") 
 echo $v3 
 v3= $(bc <<< "scale=4;$v1 % $v2") 
 echo $v3
 v3 = $(bc <<< "scale=4;$v1 * $v2") 
 echo $v3
```

the output i am getting is below :

```
mint@mint ~ $ bash bc.sh 
bc.sh: line 4: 48.41: command not found

bc.sh: line 6: -41.59: command not found

bc.sh: line 8: .0757: command not found

bc.sh: line 10: .0035: command not found

bc.sh: line 12: v3: command not found
```

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 6):

Whitespace does matter. Remove it.

```
v3= $(bc <<< "scale=4;$v1 + $v2")
   ^
```

---

Explanation: 
The following command runs `app` with a locally exported `var` with a value `value`:

```
var=value app
```

In your case `value` is empty.

Comment: Ah....thanks a lot for your help.Multiplication also works now only by removing that extra space. :)